# Render Clean Diffuse Colour Only Blender 2.81

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, eevee-render-engine

I'm trying to render an image with an output that is the pure diffuse colour only.
In earlier versions of Blender I would have just used the internal renderer and created emission materials. But, in 2.8 with Cycles or Eevee, there is always a slight noise on the image.

In the viewport with viewport shading, it gives the result I'm after.
[image: Viewport Screenshot]

With the default Eevee samples I get this result with soft edges and a noise in the flat colours.
[image: Eevee Render Default Samples]

If I set Eevee's samples to 1 I get clean edges, but still a subtle noise in the flat colours.
[image: Eevee 1 Sample]

I know the noise is very subtle, but I need it to be a solid colour. I was hoping I could use the compositor to get just the diffuse, but I couldn't figure out how. I still ended up with the noise in the result.

Thanks for your help
Dan

Comment: If you want flat uniform colors perhaps the workbench engine is more suitable for this task? Otherwise set the *Filter Size* to zero in *Render Properties > Film*, disable dithering in *Output Properties > Post Processing* and save the image in a format that supports lossless compression (to avoid compression artifacts).

Comment: @RobertGützkow Yes, it was the post processing dithering that was the issue. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello and welcome bro!

I suppose the thing is [post processing noise dither](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/output/settings.html#dithering) from Properties > Output

1. Dither intensity = 1:
   [image: Dither intensity = 1]
2. Dither intensity = 0:
   [image: Dither intensity = 0]
3. Dither intensity = 2:
   [image: Dither intensity = 2:]

Comment: This is spot on. I thought I was going mad. What was really throwing me is that if you right click on the rendered result to sample the image colours, they don't change across the noise! If I saved it, however, and sampled the colours in an external app it showed the different colours.
Anyway, thanks for your help and thank you for the kind welcome.